# Import code from git to Linux ide e.g. kdevelop

Tags: c++, linux, git, bitcoin

How can I easily import c++ classes and headers from a git project into my IDE. I dont want to download the project and then import every class seperately, but instead import the whole project, also if there is no .project file or something like that.

I use kdevelop but I can switch to another freely available IDE for Linux.

It would also be great to automatically update the source code and watch changes. Does anyone know if there is a feature for this in KDevelop or another freely available IDE?

The source code I want to completely import into my IDE is the Bitcoin Core Client source code.

Comment: Have you tried the "Fetch project" dialog from the "Project" menu?

Comment: Qtcreator has a decent git integration including a nice wizard to clone projects from remote repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is git integration in kDevelop.
You can import the project directly from github: open the Project tab, right mouse click select `Fetch Project...` and fill in necessary details - kDevelop will create the project file for you (*.kdev4).

Comment: @cryptix As a `Source` you need to type: `https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git`